# Fibonacci Series Indexing (?) Explanation

Tags: python, fibonacci

I am aware that this may be a simple question but I nevertheless require clarification, please.

So here is a simple Fibonacci series that takes in an input integer and outputs the Series up to the entered number:

```
Fibonacci_Series = []
for i in range(0, n+1):
    if i == 0 or i == 1:
        Fibonacci_Series.append(i)
    else:
        number = (Fibonacci_Series[i-1]) + (Fibonacci_Series[i-2])
        Fibonacci_Series.append(number)
print("The Fibonacci Series is {}".format(Fibonacci_Series))
```

The output is correct (n = 8):

```
The Fibonacci Series is [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21]
```

So I tried to start the series from 1 as its first element, made some changes and figured that the following works:

```
for i in range(1, n+1):
    if i == 1 or i == 2:
        Fibonacci_Series.append(1)
    else:
        number = (Fibonacci_Series[i-2]) + (Fibonacci_Series[i-3])
        Fibonacci_Series.append(number)
```

My question is, why does `(Fibonacci_Series[i-2]) + (Fibonacci_Series[i-3])` work in the latter case and gives the right series but throws an error when I use `[i-1]` and `[i-2]` from the former code? Is this because I changed my range to `range(1, n+1)`?
Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: See ["Explain something to me" Questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271468/explain-x-to-me-questions-how-to-react)

Answer (score 0):

The first time the else clause is ran, `i=3`. The length of the list is 2. You to access index 2.

```
[i-1]->[3-1]->[2]
```

Lists in python start at index 0, so in a list of length 2, you can only index 0 or 1. Trying to index 2 will result in an IndexError.